# What is the appropriate hook for hiding/editing user data?

Tags: users, hooks

We have a field on the user that I just need to hide one field from. This user object may be loaded from an API service endpoint or just in a regular login. Is there a hook I can use to obfuscate the field? Or something in the admin panel I can do?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Is this a content type that you have created or is this the default users profile page Eg : mywebsite.com/user/userid

Comment: Its not a created content type, It should be the default user object. It is not the default page though.

Comment: If its the default page you can just easily add or remove fields from the configuration page. admin/config/people/accounts. Or check this link for the user related hooks. https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21user.api.php/8.2.x

Comment: I can't provide a specific page because I am trying to write something that will generally prevent this field from ever being sent to any client. So whenever user data is loaded.

Comment: The default page wont be adequate

Comment: You could just create a new object on your own and add the fields that you need to show for your user

Comment: Yes, such an object already exists, the user.data service: `\Drupal::service('user.data')->set('mymodule', $uid, 'myvalue', $myvalue);` More info https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21src%21UserData.php/class/UserData/8.7.x